# Possible to edit top, bottom, right and left padding for UIToolBar in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, padding, uitoolbar

I was wondering if its possible to edit edit top, bottom, right and left padding for UIToolBar? I've seen some solutions to edit right and left padding, but none on how to edit top and bottom padding.

So is it even possible to edit top + bottom padding on a UIToolbar? if yes how?